# RailsTutorial: what's the difference between signup_path and user_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

I'm in chapter 7 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I'm having a hard time understanding the "_path"s that he calls on for a particular test (section 7.3.4 to be exact). Here's the code in question:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                           email: "user@invalid",
                           password:              "foo",
                           password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end
end
```

In particular, I'm confused about `get signup_path` and `post users_path`. When I go back and search the book for `signup_path`, Table 5.1 indicates it is the named route for `[sample_app url]/signup` which should direct visitors to the signup page of the website. Additionally, when I search the book for `users_path`, Table 7.1 indicates that it is the named route for `[sample_app url]/users` using the 'create' controller action because we are issuing a `POST` HTTP request.

NOTE: In responses, **please** don't suggest altering this code. This is based on Hartl's Rails Tutorial and the assumption is that the code is correct and should work *as is*. Please make sure your answers explain the code I've posted (or other code from his tutorial) and not modifications to the existing code.

**EDIT:** OK, so I think I can see the difference between `signup_path` and `users_path`: in the routes.rb file, /signup routes to `users#new`, which means it is routed to the users controller and specifically the 'new' method of that controller. I know the result of this is loading the new.html.erb file. Part of what I don't get is -- **how does the users#new controller action know which HTML page to load? Does the 'new' method automatically call whichever view is also called 'new'? OR...** (Here's the relevant controller code for the new method:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

The other part of my problem is with users_path: `rake routes` says the POST method for /users is routes through the users#create controller/action. But my routes.rb file doesn't have a route to reflect this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get '/help' =>      'static_pages#help'
   get '/about' =>     'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact' =>   'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup' =>    'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

So the second part of the question is: **How does the routes file know to route the post users_path to the users#create controller/action?**

Comment: To answer your EDIT: Yes, it is one of Rails conventions that per default the controller will try to renders a view with the same name than the method that was called on the controller. So e.g. `UsersController#new` will look for a view named `users/new.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

The dont point to the same page, GET signup_path will GET you to the page where user can sign up while POST users_path is a different route where you send parameters that you have generate on GET signup_path.

Also you dont need to search tables to see to what URL each _path points, just type

```
rake routes
```

in command prompt and you will see what each path is.

Comment: I realized they're not the same thing after I posted, so I've edited my original question to reflect what I'm actually trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This small line

```
resources :users
```

is actually a shortcut for [*seven* different](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) (but very common) routes that cover all CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) operations on a resource. One of them is exactly:

```
users_path   POST   /users  users#create    create a new user
```